# How can I extract numbers sequence from array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array :

```
var selectedRange = [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  9, //sequences
  10,//sequences
  null,
  12,
  13,
  14,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  20,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  25,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  29,
  30,
  31,
  32,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  37,
  38,
  null,
  40,
  41,
  42,
  null,
  44,
  null,
  null,
  47,
  null,
  49,
  50,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null
]
```

I need to extract sequences of number and only numbers - so the result would be like:

```
["9,10", "12,13,14", "20", "25", "29,30,31,32", "44", "47", "49,50"]
```

The problem is that I can't come up with a solution to extract a sequence as it is, I guess I need a recursive function that repeats the part of checking if the last number and the current are following - like here ...(!!prm && (prm - (index-1) ==1 )

```
let tempArr = [];
$.each(selectedRange, function (index, prm) {
    if (!!prm && (prm - (index - 1) == 1) {
        tempArr.push(prm); // need to loop this section with recursion 
    }
});
```

Comment: do you have the first array and want the second or vice versa?

Comment: @NinaScholz - i've updated the question - check it out - thanks

Comment: `JSON.stringify(selectedRange).match(/([^null, ])+/g)` would be an interesting start

Comment: can you work with array of arrays instead of putting sequences in a string?

Comment: why not just filter out null elements? @mplungjan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to join into a comma delimited string and then split apart the empty elements. Add a final filter to remove leading or trailing empty elements.  This might not be the most efficient.

```js
var selectedRange = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 9, 10, null, 12, 13, 14, null, null, null, null, null, 20, null, null, null, null, 25, null, null, null, 29, 30, 31, 32, null, null, null, null, 37, 38, null, 40, 41, 42, null, 44, null, null, 47, null, 49, 50, null, null, null, null, null, null ]

console.log(
  selectedRange.join(',').split(/,,+|^,|,$/).filter(Boolean)
)
```

(Edited to incorporate comment-suggestions from @KooiInc and @Ifaruki.)

Comment: Won't work if `selectedRange` looks like `[9, null, null, 10, null, null, 11, ...]`

Comment: @KooiInc why won't it work if the input equals [9, null, null, 10, null, null, 11, ...]?  When I try it I get ["9", "10", "11"].  What do you expect?

Comment: Try  `console.log([null, 8, null, null, null, 9, 10, null].join(',').split(/,,+/).filter((v) => v !== ""));`. It will result in: `[ ',8', '9,10,' ]`

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)` would be a more elegant way, atleast in my opinion

Comment: @KooiInc that is an excellent point. The quick fix is to amend the split, which I'll do.  Though, I feel like there should be a clearer way to express it, but it doesn't leap to mind.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Ifaruki you're right! I was momentarily worried about 0, but it is already stringified.

Comment: Your fix is not working like it should: try replacing 25 with 21 in `selectedRange`

Comment: @KooiInc, I'm not sure you're still specifying the same problem as the OP specified.

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate the array and have a look to the predecessor.

```js
let selectedRange = [null, 8, null, null, null, 9, 10, null],
    result = [],
    last;

for (const value of selectedRange) {
    if (value === null) continue;
    if (last + 1 === value) result[result.length - 1] += `,${value}`;
    else result.push(value.toString());
    last = value;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You're missing the intermediate values within ranges

Comment: Yep. Now try it with `[null, 8, null, null, null, 9, 10, null]`. Spoiler: will result in `[ '8', '9,10' ]` ;)

Comment: plus 1: you fixed it ;P

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do this operation as follows.

```js
var selectedRange = [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 9, 10, null, 12, 13, 14, null, null, null, null, null, 20, null, null, null, null, 25, null, null, null, 29, 30, 31, 32, null, null, null, null, 37, 38, null, 40, 41, 42, null, 44, null, null, 47, null, 49, 50, null, null, null, null, null, null ];

let split = null;
const output = selectedRange.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur) {
    split ? split += "," + cur : split = `${cur}`;
  } else {
    if (split) {
      acc.push(split);
      split = null;
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```js
var selectedRange = [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 9, 10, null, 12, 13, 14, null, null, null, null, null, 20, null, null, null, null, 25, null, null, null, 29, 30, 31, 32, null, null, null, null, 37, 38, null, 40, 41, 42, null, 44, null, null, 47, null, 49, 50, null, null, null, null, null, null ];

let isNullSeq = true;
const arr = [];
let temp = '';
selectedRange.forEach((item) => {
  if (item) {
    if (isNullSeq) {
      temp = temp + item;
      isNullSeq = false;
    } else {
      temp += ',';
      temp += item;
    }
  } else {
    if (!isNullSeq) {
      isNullSeq = true;
      arr.push(temp);
      temp = '';
    }
  }
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you only have nulls in between - how about something simpler?

```js
var selectedRange = [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 9, 10, null, 12, 13, 14, null, null, null, null, null, 20, null, null, null, null, 25, null, null, null, 29, 30, 31, 32, null, null, null, null, 37, 38, null, 40, 41, 42, null, 44, null, null, 47, null, 49, 50, null, null, null, null, null, null]
console.log(selectedRange.toString().replace(/,{2,}/g, ',,').split(",,").filter(function(el) { return el != "";}))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`, you can get them from an utility library like Ramda or implement them by yourself.

```js
const inputs = [
  [1,2,null,null,5,6,7,null,null,10,11],
  [null,null,3,4,null],
  [1,2,null,null,5,null,null],
  [null],
  [1],
  [null, 1],
  [],
];

const takeWhile = (predicate) => ([head, ...tail]) => {
  if (head === undefined || !predicate (head)) return [];
  return [head].concat (takeWhile (predicate) (tail));
}

const dropWhile = (predicate) => ([head, ...tail]) => {
  if (head === undefined) return [];
  if (!predicate (head)) return [head, ...tail];
  return dropWhile (predicate) (tail);
};

const isNull = x => x === null;
const isNotNull = x =>  x !== null;

const sequence = (list) => {
  if (list.length === 0) return [];
  if (list[0] === null) return sequence (dropWhile (isNull) (list));
  return [takeWhile (isNotNull) (list).join (',')].concat (
    sequence (dropWhile (isNotNull) (list))
  );
}

console.log (inputs.map (sequence));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediate array of sequence arrays using `Array.reduce`and map the resulting sequences to strings

```js
const selectedRange = [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,9, 10,null,12,13,14,null,null,null,null,null,20,null,null,null,null,25,null,null,null,29,30,31,32,null,null,null,null,37,38,null,40,41,42,null,44,null,null,47,null,49,50,null,null,null,null,null,null];

// the reducer lambda
const sequenceReducer = (acc, val) =>
  !val ? acc : val - 1 === acc.flat().pop() ?
    acc[acc.length-1].push(val) && acc : [...acc, [].concat(val)];

console.log( JSON.stringify( selectedRange.reduce(sequenceReducer, []).map( v => v.join() ) ) );

// let's try discontinuous sequences (numbers are not consecutive)
const x = [null, 8, null, null, null, 9, 10, null, 11, null, null, 12, null, 14, null, 15, null, null, 16];
console.log( JSON.stringify( x.reduce(sequenceReducer, []).map( v => v.join() ) ) );

// sequences are discontinuous AND not ordered. Sort first
// (and by the way, note the negative values)
const y = [26, 13, null, 8, null, -3, null, 9, 25, 10, null, 11, null, 7, 12, null, 14, -2, 15, null, 17, 16, -1];
const sortSequenceArray = (a, b) => +a - +b;
console.log( JSON.stringify( y.sort(sortSequenceArray).reduce(sequenceReducer, []).map( v => v.join() ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

By taking into consideration sequence like given in question (9, 10,..., - seq = diff of `1`). Following
code will produce the the required result -

```js
var selectedRange = [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  9, //sequences
  10,//sequences
  null,
  12,
  13,
  14,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  20,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  25,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  29,
  30,
  31,
  32,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  37,
  38,
  null,
  40,
  41,
  42,
  null,
  44,
  null,
  null,
  47,
  null,
  49,
  50,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null
]
 

selectedRange = selectedRange.filter(v => v)
var finalArray = [], temp = [];
for(var i=0; i<selectedRange.length; i++)
{
    if(selectedRange[i+1]-selectedRange[i] > 1 )
    {
        temp.push(selectedRange[i]);
        
        finalArray.push(temp.join(","));
        temp.length = 0;

    }    
    else temp.push(selectedRange[i])

}
finalArray.push(temp.join(","));

console.log(finalArray);
```